# Design-time data not showing when creating a UWP MVVM Light project

Tags: xaml, mvvm-light, uwp, uwp-xaml

When creating a MVVM Light UWP app, I am not able to get programmatic design time data working via my View Model. I believe this may be due to Visual Studio 2015 adding in the property names of the bindings in the designer instead. I have confirm this be creating a blank MvvmLight (Win10Univ) app in the project templates (MVVM Light 2015 for VS2015 - Version 5.2.0.0) and it clearly shows "WelcomeTitle", the name of the property instead of "Welcome to MVVM Light [design]" that is set up in the `DesignDataService` class.

[MVVM Light Main Page capture in designer showing incorrect design time data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9A1hY.png)

When seeing this problem in my own project, I am using something like this in my View Model:

```
if (this.IsInDesignMode)
{
    // Load design time data when in design mode
    this.Duration = "2 HRS 13 MINS";
}
```

I am then binding to the property in my View with the data context set as follows:

```
<Page.DataContext>
        <Binding Path="FooBarPageViewModel" Source="{StaticResource Locator}" />
</Page.DataContext>
```

Now, normally the above is all you need to do as per the MVVM Light project template app, but I have tried to following with no success:

```
d:DataContext="{Binding FooBarPageViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

I have also tried using x:Bind, but still see the same problem.

So does anybody know how to resolve this problem or has come across something similar?

Note: This issue may not be just related to MVVM Light and could instead be a UWP platform issue.

Comment: I've just created the template you mention and see exactly what you mean  but strangley design time data started working after I run the app. weird as the const `WelcomeTitlePropertyName = "WelcomeTitle"` is not used as far as I could tell

Comment: Did you build app? And x:Bind doesn't support deisgn-time data

Comment: @DavidKosorin, Yes, I built the template app on x64, but still don't see "Welcome to MVVM Light [design]" in the designer. Okay, good to know that x:Bind doesn't design time data.

Comment: Hmmm, just changed the build architecture to x86 and now I see the design time data! I guess the VS designer doesn't support x64 for design time data?

Comment: @SandipAhluwalia yep I can confirm what you said switched to x64 and design time data disappeared. Learn something new every day :) Put it in an answer yourself and mark as correct so others see it

Comment: I swear to god, this damn UWP XAML designer is entirely broken! I had to change to x64 for it to appear, and it only worked the 2nd time I tried it! The entire designer is broken from every single point, it's absolutely infuriating!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so building the template MVVM Light UWP app in x86 architecture allows you to see the design time data in the Visual Studio designer. However, a few of points:

- When in x86 mode, you have to enable the project code button in the designer to see the design time data.
- If you have a combination of x:bind and runtime binding in the XAML page using x86 then the designer crashes. You can disable the project code in the designer to fix the crash, but then design time data won't work again.
- When in x64 mode, it seems you can't enable the project code button, thus resulting in this original problem.